# How to make a String Array by reading a table?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox, textbox

I currently have a combobox on my form that lists all US states, Puerto Rico and District of Colombia.

I need to change that combobox into a normal textbox that has all the state codes in an array so that when the user clicks the ok button the textbox gets validated by going through the "state" array to find out if said code exists.

**How do I use a query to load table information into an array that can be transferred into a textbox?**

This is the current code that puts information into the combo box

```
Private Sub LoadStateComboBox()
    Dim stateList As List(Of State)
    Try
        stateList = StateDB.GetStateList
        cboStates.DataSource = stateList
        cboStates.DisplayMember = "StateName"
        cboStates.ValueMember = "StateCode"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

-->11:47pm By changing the DisplayMember to StateCode the comboBox now displays the codes. Can I just switch the code over to a normal textbox and it will be in there?

Comment: What type do you want the array to be?  An array of `State` objects, or an array of `String` objects (taken from some property of each of the `State` objects in the original `stateList`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to VB. I have a file in Access named MMABOOKS.mdb, it has a table "States." I want to read the StateCode column and transfer all that data into a String? array so that when the user input "WI" it will run through the array and check to see its real.

Comment: If the user puts in "ZA" it will come back and say that ZA is not a valid state code and bring up an error message

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array of `State` objects, that's really easy.  You can just call the `List(Of T).ToArray` method, like this:

```
Dim stateArray() As State = stateList.ToArray()
```

If you want to get an array of strings, though, where the strings in the array are taken from one property of each of the `State` objects in the original list, that's a little more difficult, but still pretty easy with LINQ.  For instance, if the `State` class contains a `StateCode As String` property, you could get an array of all the state codes with LINQ, like this:

```
Dim stateCodeArray() As String = stateList.Select(Of String)(Function(x) x.StateCode).ToArray()
```